# JAVA Match a Username with a Password for Login Program

Tags: java, file-io

I am coding a login program that allows you to set and store a password and username in two separate files (named accordingly). My problem is I can't figure out how to set a username to a password. Ex: Username is Bob, Password is cat, and the user needs to input Bob as the username and cat as the password or else it gives an error(if the user inputs the username as bill and the password as cat, it should detect that the username doesn't go with its respective password). Any help would be nice. *I have not added the username part yet as it is structured the same as the password part, I just need the username to correspond with the password so that the user cannot use a different username with the same password

Here is my code I have so far for a reference:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class PassCode
{
    static String adminPassword = "Change Password";
    public static void fileMaker() throws IOException 
    {
        PrintStream standard = System.out;
        File f = new File("Password.txt");
        FileOutputStream fs= new FileOutputStream(f);
        PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(fs);
        System.setOut(ps);
        String theMessage = "Set New Password";
        String userInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(theMessage);
        System.out.println(userInput);
        ps.close();
        System.setOut(standard);
    }
public static void Checker() throws IOException
    {
        Scanner inputStream = new Scanner(new FileReader("Password.txt")); //Scans declared file for text on the first line
        String fileChecker = inputStream.nextLine(); //Sets scanned line into a string variable
        if(fileChecker.isEmpty())
        {
            fileMaker();
        }
        else
        {
        int reply = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Would you like to change the current password", "Warning!", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
        if (reply == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) 
          {
              String inquire = "Type Administrator Password to Proceed";
              boolean flag = true;
              while(flag == true)
          {
              String confirm = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(inquire);
          if(confirm.equals(adminPassword))
          {
              fileMaker();
              flag = false;
          }
          else
          {
              inquire = "Incorrect!" + "\n" + "Retry";
          }
          }
        }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        Checker();
        Scanner inputStreamThree = new Scanner(new FileReader("Password.txt"));
        String line = inputStreamThree.nextLine();
        String question = "Password Please";
        Boolean right = true;
         while(right == true)
        {
            String ask = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(question); //Asks for user to input password
        if(ask.equals(adminPassword)) //Checks if user input the admin password
        {
            fileMaker();
            Scanner inputStreamAdmin = new Scanner(new FileReader("Password.txt")); //Scans for admin password
            String adminChecker = inputStreamAdmin.nextLine(); //Sets scanned line as a new string variable
            line = adminChecker;
        }
        else if(line.equals(ask)) //Checks if user password is correct
        {
            System.out.println("Welcome Fellow Programmer to the Now Functioning Password Checker!" + 
                "\n" + "Date Today: 10/31/2017" + 
                "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n" + "Did you figure out the Admin password yet?");
            right = false;
        }
        else if(ask != line) //Checks if user password is incorrect
            {
               question = "Incorrect Password!";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is having two different files a requirement?

Comment: It is preferred, but if there is another way around it then it would be fine. Also, I wanted to use two different files to store both the passwords and usernames separately.

Answer (score 0):

If both username and password are located in the same line number in their respective file, then it should be possible to deduct the right password for a given user.

Example:

```
Username.txt                       Password.txt
bob                                cat
alice                              rabbit
victor                             salmon
```

When searching the username, count the line read until you find the username. Then in the password file, read the number of lines and retrieve the password value. Then compare!

I assume this is academic work because storing password in clear in files is a major security hole and should never be allowed on professional project.

Comment: I will try that! That seems like it will be the answer I am looking for. P.S. This is academic work, I just wanted to make a simple program to understand how a basic login program functions and then optimize it according to the flaws(which are very obvious as this is a program to teach).

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you use only single login but stored on 2 files Password.txt and Username.txt.

Below is my 10 min codes, so you might need to modified if got typo or error.

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class PassCodeA {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner usernameFile = null;
        try {
            usernameFile = new Scanner(new FileReader("Username.txt"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Username File Missing", "File Missing", JOptionPane.CLOSED_OPTION);
            return;
        }

        Scanner passwordFile = null;
        try {
            passwordFile = new Scanner(new FileReader("Password.txt"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Password File Missing", "File Missing", JOptionPane.CLOSED_OPTION);
            return;
        }

        String usernameInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Please Enter Username", "Username", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
        String passwordInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Please Enter Password", "Username", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
        System.out.println(usernameInput);

        boolean usernameFound = false;
        while(usernameFile.hasNextLine()){
            final String lineFromFile = usernameFile.nextLine();
            if(lineFromFile.equals(usernameInput)){
                usernameFound = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (usernameFound == false) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Username not found", "Username Not Found", JOptionPane.CLOSED_OPTION);
            return;
        }

        boolean passwordFound = false;
        while(passwordFile.hasNextLine()){
            final String lineFromFile = passwordFile.nextLine();
            if(lineFromFile.equals(passwordInput)){
                passwordFound = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (passwordFound == false) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Password not found", "Password Not Found", JOptionPane.CLOSED_OPTION);
            return;
        }

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Thank you for login", "Success", JOptionPane.CLOSED_OPTION);


    }



}
```

If you had multiple login credential in that both files. You should use LineNumberReader instead of scanner. So that you can match with line number on both files.

Comment: I will also give that a try tomorrow and see what results it yields. Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to implement LineNumberReader(LNR) and have the program check if the line numbers for both the username and password are the same. I used a separate method and called it in the main method. I tested the code and it worked with multiple username info and password info in both files. I know this is messy as well, but I was going for functionality first. Then I will optimize it accordingly. I cannot upload the whole code as it is way to big for space given.

Here is the code I added(just the method with the LNR):

```
public static void reader() throws IOException
    {
        JTextField username = new JTextField();
        JTextField password = new JPasswordField();
        Object[] message = {
            "Username:", username,
            "Password:", password
             };

        int option = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, message, "Login", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);


        boolean right = true;

        while(right == true)
        {
        int u = 0;
        String userCheck;
        FileReader ur = null;
        LineNumberReader lnru = null;

        try {

        ur = new FileReader("username.txt");
        lnru = new LineNumberReader(ur);

        while ((userCheck = lnru.readLine()) != null)
        {
            if (userCheck.equals(username.getText()))
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                u = lnru.getLineNumber();
            }
        }
      } catch(Exception e)
        {
          e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
                if(ur!=null)
                    ur.close();
                if(lnru!=null)
                    lnru.close();
            }

        int p = 0;
        String passCheck;
        FileReader pr = null;
        LineNumberReader lnrp = null;

        try {

        pr = new FileReader("Password.txt");
        lnrp = new LineNumberReader(pr);

        while ((passCheck = lnrp.readLine()) != null)
        {
            if (passCheck.equals(password.getText()))
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                p = lnrp.getLineNumber();
            }
        }
    } catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {

            if(pr!=null)
                pr.close();
            if(lnrp!=null)
                lnrp.close();
        }

        if (option == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION)
        {
         if(password.getText().equals(adminPassword)) //Checks if user input the admin password
        {
            passMaker();
            Scanner inputStreamAdmin = new Scanner(new FileReader("Password.txt")); //Scans for admin password
            String adminChecker = inputStreamAdmin.nextLine(); //Sets scanned line as a new string variable
            //lineFromFile = adminChecker;
        }
        else if(p == u) //Checks if username and password are correct
        {
            System.out.println("Welcome Fellow Programmer to the Now Functioning login program!" + "\n" + "Date Today: 10/31/2017" + "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n" + "Did you figure out the Admin password yet?");
            right = false;
        }
        else  //Checks if user password is incorrect
            {
               option = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, message, "Login Failed Try Again", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
            }
        }
     }
    }
```